Definition of an adaptive threshold for signal detection
Good day. I would like to try to create a signal detection algorithm based on STFT. I am interested in the implementation of an adaptive detection threshold that will be determined per bin (by frequency samples). The main problem currently is that I am using bladeRF for experiments, and it has sharp filter roll-off and artifacts at low gain, which are described here: https://github.com/Nuand/bladeRF/issues/732. Perhaps someone has encountered this or can suggest articles or code examples for implementing such an algorithm.

Seems like you might be interested in Constant False Alarm Rate (CFAR) detection.
